# Is it possible to integrate RSForm Pro with the Exacttarget API?

Tags: marketing-cloud, api, contact, php

I've done quite a bit of research on Google about this but there doesn't seem to be much information on this subject. Is it possible to integrate RSForm Pro with the Exacttarget API? If so, where does one host the PHP files that the ET API uses as dependencies?

Currently, the line of attack I'm taking is to host them elsewhere on a different server but I'm wondering if there's a better way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Any libraries you use with the API would need to be hosted. You can host these on your server or on Heroku.

Since you are using PHP, I would suggest trying the Fuel PHP SDK -> https://github.com/ExactTarget/FuelSDK-PHP

> The Fuel SDK for PHP provides easy access to ExactTarget's Fuel API
>   Family services, including a collection of REST APIs and a SOAP API.
>   These APIs provide access to ExactTarget functionality via common
>   collection types such as array/hash.